# Insert into Firebase Database in Java

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to insert data into firebase Database using Java? I have created an app and  want to save its data inside my firebase account. 
If yes, how do I achieve this?
I read that using the SDK for android can also be used in the Java application, but I want to confirm.

I am planning to use a JS file to send data to Firebase and just call it inside the Java Application, with the Data to be sent as arguments. Still have to test this, but I'm also looking for an easier alternative.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
Read the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

There is the example from the Google itself: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-java/tree/master/database

Comment: Thank you! I decided to go with python-based processing, cause i have a really slow internet and can't download large files. Thank you by the way!